# Can't install packages from PPAs (Elementary OS)

Tags: software-installation, elementary-os, ppa

I'm unable to install any packages from PPAs in Elementary OS.

```
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package elementary-tweaks
```

I've run sudo apt-get update and found the correct PPAs. This has happened with any package I've tried to get from a PPA:

- Conky Manager
- Elementary Tweaks
- Sublime Text 3
- Nvidia Drivers
  (I later downloaded some of these manually from websites)

I'm able to add the PPAs, but not install the packages. :(

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
```

If you have never added a PPA on Loki before, you might need to run this command first:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Also, you can build it by your own.

```
sudo apt-get install libgconf2-dev libpolkit-gobject-1-dev libswitchboard-2.0-dev elementary-sdk
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr ../
make 

sudo make install 
switchboard
```

Comment: I''ve already run all the commands listed in the first solution. I did try the second solution, but I got: `
E: Unable to locate package libswitchboard-2.0-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libswitchboard-2.0-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libswitchboard-2.0-dev'
E: Unable to locate package elementary-sdk`

Comment: Run this command: `grep -RoPish '(?<=ppa.launchpad.net/)[^/]+/[^/ ]+' /etc/apt | sort -u | sed 's/^/ppa:/'` and show list of PPA it produces.

Comment: Is a proxy set in your System?  `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @GermanLashevich `ppa:elementary-os/os-patches
ppa:elementary-os/stable
ppa:justsomedood/onlyelementary
ppa:linrunner/tlp
ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily
ppa:teejee2008/ppa
ppa:versable/elementary-update
ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-2
ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
`

Comment: @Bahamut the only thing it produces is `nameserver 127.0.1.1`

Comment: show `route -n` You can serve with your internet-browser?

Comment: `Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.5.16.1       0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
10.0.100.10     10.5.16.1       255.255.255.255 UGH   600    0        0 wlp2s0
10.5.16.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0
`

Comment: @Bahamut yes I can use my internet browser.

Comment: theris no gateway in your `/etc/resolv.conf´ Add `gateway 10.5.16.1`